Is it okay to ask if your muslim friend likes you
I'm in a situation where I'm contemplating asking my Muslim friend if they like me, and I'm uncertain if it's appropriate to do so. I want to be respectful and mindful of any cultural or religious considerations that might affect this conversation. Although I'm not Muslim, I'm open to converting if we decide to get married. Could someone offer advice on whether it is okay to ask this question and how to approach it in a way that respects both our friendship and their beliefs? Your guidance would be greatly appreciated.
